# why is my content div not in the wrapper div

Tags: html, css

My problem is that my 'content' `div` doesn't stay inside the 'sitewrapper' `div`.

### HTML:

```
<div class="sitewraper">
   <div class="categorietree">
      <?php echo $categorietree; ?>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <?php echo $content; ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
div.sitewrapper
{
    height:99%;
    width:100%;
    top:75px !important;
    position:relative;
}

div.categorietree
{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
}

div.content
{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
}
```

This is the problem:

[image]

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: you might have closed 1 extra </div> in your categorietree..

Comment: Is your PHP variables containing values with tags?

Comment: Show the rendered HTML. But most likely as others mentioned an extra closing `</div>`.

Comment: hey @DaanKleijngeld Then you should select the answer of digitalextremist

Comment: @Zword OK thanks. my english is bad but now i understand he means the same

Comment: I included some code for you @DaanKleijngeld

Comment: **HTML**: `<div class="sitewraper">`, **CSS**:  `div.sitewrapper`, find the missing *p*. Not sure if it is related to your problem.

Comment: An HTML validator would have found the problem for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Either:

1. Your javascript libraries re-arrange elements in the DOM ( *but this is unlikely** ).
2. Your dynamic `$content` or `$categorietree` injections contain an extra `</div>` tag!

*Libraries like jQuery Mobile usually only move elements into and out of the library's special elements, they don't single out and mess with other elements.

## It's probably #2.

Make sure to clean out and sanitize HTML if content is ever being injected dynamically!

**Simple test:** Use this function on your content before echoing it: http://www.php.net/strip_tags

### So, try this...

```
<div class="sitewraper">
   <div class="categorietree">
      <?php echo strip_tags( $categorietree ); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <?php echo strip_tags( $content ); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```